# How to uncheck the checked element on removal of its tag in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a checkbox and a tag component. On checking each element a tag of that element is displayed below which is achieved by the below code. But I want to map each tag with the respective checkbox element. When I remove the tag of an element, the corresponding element should be unchecked from the checkbox. Link to my code https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-borg-77nlv

```
import { Checkbox, Tag, Button } from "antd";
class Filters extends Component {
  state = {
    tags: []
  };
  onCheck = value => {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    console.log("The values", value);
    value.map(el => !tags.includes(el) && tags.push(el));
    this.setState({ tags });
  };
  onCheck1 = value => {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    value.map(el => !tags.includes(el) && tags.push(el));
    this.setState({ tags });
    console.log("The values", value);
  };
  onCloseTag = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tags: this.state.tags.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { tags } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          CHECKBOX 1
          <Checkbox.Group
            name="checkbox_1"
            onChange={this.onCheck}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <Checkbox value="a">A</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox value="b">B</Checkbox>
          </Checkbox.Group>
        </div>
        <div>
          CHECKBOX 2
          <Checkbox.Group
            name="checkbox_2"
            onChange={this.onCheck1}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <Checkbox value="2a">2A</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox value="2b">2B</Checkbox>
          </Checkbox.Group>
        </div>
        <div style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
          {tags.map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag
              className="quick-filter-tag-main"
              key={i}
              closable
              onClose={e => this.onCloseTag(e, i)}
              color="#f50"
            >
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

When an element say **a** is checked it will be displayed as a tag below. If I remove the tag , the **a** should be unchecked.

Comment: Your checkboxes are not controled by the the state value

Comment: pls accept answer if its ok

Comment: Is there any other implementation with checkbox group .

Answer (score 1):

Hi  if you don't want to use checkbox group you can simplifiy your code like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-morse-ffkez

filter.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Checkbox, Tag, Button } from "antd";
class Filters extends Component {
  state = {
    tags: []
  };

  onCheck = e => {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    tags = tags.filter(v => v !== e.target.value);

    e.target.checked && tags.push(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ tags });
  };

  onCloseTag = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tags: this.state.tags.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { tags } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          CHECKBOX 1
          <Checkbox
            onChange={this.onCheck}
            checked={tags.includes("a")}
            value="a"
          >
            A
          </Checkbox>
          <Checkbox
            onChange={this.onCheck}
            checked={tags.includes("b")}
            value="b"
          >
            B
          </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <div>
          CHECKBOX 2
          <Checkbox
            onChange={this.onCheck}
            checked={tags.includes("2a")}
            value="2a"
          >
            2A
          </Checkbox>
          <Checkbox
            onChange={this.onCheck}
            checked={tags.includes("2b")}
            value="2b"
          >
            2B
          </Checkbox>
        </div>
        <div style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
          {tags.map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag
              className="quick-filter-tag-main"
              key={i}
              closable
              onClose={e => this.onCloseTag(e, i)}
              color="#f50"
            >
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Filters;
```